# Rename localhost to custom domain using webpack dev server?

Tags: webpack, dns, localhost, webpack-dev-server, hosts

I'm trying to rename my `localhost` that I use on development.

I have updated my `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file and added this line (ran as Administrator):

```
# copyright (c) 1993-2009 microsoft corp.
#
# this is a sample hosts file used by microsoft tcp/ip for windows.
#
# this file contains the mappings of ip addresses to host names. each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. the ip address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# the ip address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# for example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within dns itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1        my-dev-environment.com         // <===== ADDED THIS LINE
127.0.0.1:8080   my-dev-environment.com         // <===== I ALSO TRIED THIS
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
This site can’t be reached
"my-dev-environment.com" refused to connect
```

I'm using `webpack-dev-server` to develop, and here is my current config for it:

**webpack.config.js**

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: './public',
    compress: true,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: '/app.html'
    },
    index: 'app.html'
  },
```

**QUESTION**

Am I doing something wrong? Why isn't it working?

---

**UPDATE (SOLVED):**

Following @Joel recommendations from the answer below, I've added this to my `webpack.config.js`

```
devServer: {
  public: 'my-dev-environment.com',
  port: 80,                       
}
```

And this is on my `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1        my-dev-environment.com
```

Now I can access it on `my-dev-environment.com`

Comment: Restart any open browsers, flush dns cache. then you should be good to go. Also, try `127.0.0.1       localhost my-dev-environment.com`

Comment: Thanks! How to `flush dns cache` ?

Comment: windows + r => `ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: Then, if the above didnt work. Restart your machine :)

Comment: @Joel Hey Joel, just tried everything. Including restarting my PC and nothing worked! Could this be related to some `webpack-dev-server` config?

Comment: this shouldn't be the case but, what port is your running application running on? try accessing it through my-dev-environment:thatport in your browser. (since you cannot allocate a custom port in your host-file, i think this is the way to go)

Comment: @Joel don't think so. Regular Windows 10 installation. I did all the config myself for the `webpack` config files. It runs fine on `localhost:8080`. But somehow I can't get it to recognize the `hosts` file config alias.

Comment: in hosts. do `localhost my-dev-environment.com` and `127.0.0.1 my-dev-envionment.com` then access it with `http://my-dev-environment.com:8080`. Clear dns-cache and restart browsers first.

Comment: When I try `my-dev-environment:8080` I get `Invalid Host header`

Comment: Okay, kill webpack, restart it using launch args `--host 0.0.0.0`. This might be needed too: `--disable-host-check`

Comment: You can also try to start your webpack using `--public my-dev-environment.com:8080`

Comment: This works! Hosts file: `127.0.0.1 my-dev-environment.com` and `devServer: public: 'my-dev-environment.com:8080'`. This is making my local environment accessible on `my-dev-environment.com:8080`. Do you think it's possible to configure it to omit the `port` part? And be accessible through `my-dev-environment.com` only? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Well, since `http://` defaults to 80, try changing your localhost port to 80. Then  omit :80 and add `http://` in front of your url when u try to access it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In **hosts**: `127.0.0.1 my-dev-environment.com`

Flush your DNS-Cache by running `ipconfig /flushdns`.

When launching your **webpack-dev-server**:

add the flags `--host 0.0.0.0` and `--public my-dev-environment.com:PORT`

*Is it possible to omit the `:PORT` when accessing it through the browser?*

Since `http://` defaults to `:80`. Make your application run on port `:80` instead. Unless you have an apache instance or something similar, then run it on `:8080`.

If you have an `https://` protocol, make your application run on port `:443` instead.

Comment: 100% working. Added this to my `webpack.config.js`: `devServer: { public: 'my-dev-environment.com, port: 80 }` and now I can access without the port number in the URL. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 5):

With Webpack 5, the `devserver` config changed from `public` to `host`:

```
devServer: {
  host: 'my-dev-environment.com',
  port: 8080,
}
```

Webpack docs: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhost